# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Authorization')

Tags: vue.js

My axios is not setting headers, I have tried to look for any possible solution everywhere but I am not getting any solution. Everything looks fine but when I copy the following code and paste it in a created hook method I get an error in the console reading [Vue warn]: Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Authorization')", which explained why axios does not work.

```
beforeCreated() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")         

    if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " + token

    } else {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ""
    }
}
```

Anyone who had a similar problem to help me out please. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Your token should be inside the Bearer like this:

```
beforeCreated() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token")         

    if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `"Bearer ${token}"`

    } else {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = ""
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original answer at all

Comment: It does. Check the difference.

Comment: My bad! I just spotted the mistake